# Why does IIS7 restore unwanted MSMQ bindings?

Tags: iis-7, msmq

Why does IIS7 keep restoring the following bindings, even after I have removed them?

- net.tcp 808:*
- net.pipe *
- net.msmq localhost
- msmq.formatname localhost

Is this just a property of MSMQ being installed?  Can the bindings be disabled without uninstalling MSMQ?

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Do you access MSMQ through IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find any answers, but my workaround does appear to work.

Locate the file: C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

This is effectively the web.config file for all the settings you configure through the IIS Console Manager.

> WARNING: Edit at your own risk.  If you get this wrong, it will take
>   your IIS server offline until you fix it.  You'll know if you have got
>   it wrong, as the IIS Console Manager will give you an error popup when
>   you access a website, telling you it was unable to parse this file.

Locate the section of XML under the element system.applicationHost similar to the following:

```
    <listenerAdapters>
        <add name="http" />
        <add name="net.tcp" identity="S-0-0-00-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000-000000000" />
        <add name="net.pipe" identity="S-0-0-00-0000000000-000000000-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000" />
        <add name="net.msmq" identity="S-0-0-00-00000000-0000000000-0000000000-000000000-0000000000" />
        <add name="msmq.formatname" identity="S-0-0-00-00000000-0000000000-0000000000-000000000-0000000000" />
    </listenerAdapters>
```

If you comment out the listener adapter entries for the unwanted binding types, this prevents them from being associated with your websites automatically.  I.e:

```
    <listenerAdapters>
        <add name="http" />
        <!--
        <add name="net.tcp" identity="S-0-0-00-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000-000000000" />
        <add name="net.pipe" identity="S-0-0-00-0000000000-000000000-0000000000-0000000000-0000000000" />
        <add name="net.msmq" identity="S-0-0-00-00000000-0000000000-0000000000-000000000-0000000000" />
        <add name="msmq.formatname" identity="S-0-0-00-00000000-0000000000-0000000000-000000000-0000000000" />
        -->
    </listenerAdapters>
```

Note: I have noticed that sometimes these bindings re-appear anyway, but when I looked at this file, it had new entries for these bindings added back into the file.  So far, I have never had to comment them out more than twice.